# Linear Algebra: Geometric means

Tags: geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the geometric means of

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

I would like to show that its eigenvector is not real.

Comment: The matrix $M$ gives a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. $x$ axes rotates in $\theta$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

This matrix rotates the plane by $\theta$ degrees anti-clockwise. To find its eigen values, simply solve the equation
$$
det(A-\lambda I) = 0
$$
You will get
$$
(\cos(\theta) - \lambda)^2 +\sin^2(\theta) = 0
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow 1 - 2\cos(\theta)\lambda + \lambda^2 = 0
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \lambda = \cos(\theta) \pm \sqrt{\cos^2(\theta) - 1}
$$
So your eigen values are $e^{\pm i\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, the matrix represents a rotation about the origin. Let's also assume $\theta\neq \pi n$ for any integer $n$, otherwise your matrix is $\pm$identity and does have real eigenvectors.

Anyways, the intuition is that eigenvectors of $A$ are non-zero vectors that are scaled by $A$, i.e., end up in the same direction but with a possibly different length. Can this happen in your case?